# Zend Application with Multiple login

Tags: php, zend-framework

I want to have multiple login with in single zend application.

I have five sections A,B,C,D,E and four type of users (P,Q,R,S) including anonymous user.These section have sub sections. Section A,B,C required login to access them. Section D and E can be accessed by all type of users but there are some action that can be followed by specific type of users.

P can only login to sec A, Q can login to sec B and R can login to sec C.

Can you please suggest what directory structure I should use and how should I implement multiple login.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be better to use default modules for anonymous users and make modules for all sections and use different layouts for different modules. Single login will be used for these modules and user will be redirected respective user section after logged in.
What do you say ?

Answer (score 2):

the directory structure has nothing to do with the access rights. your whole application could be a single controller and be capable of your roles and rights concept but would not be nice code tbh.

if you don't wanna use Zend_Acl (why not?) you could solve it by implementing a simple concept like the following:

create an application module for each of your "sections" including a PublicController in each application which will be accessible by anyone later.
then you should implement a front controller plugin which could look like the folloing

```
public function preDispatch()
{
    $identity = Zend_Auth::getInstance()->getIdentity();        
    $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
    $controller = $this->getRequest()->getControllerName();

    if($controller == 'public') {

        return;
    }

    switch ($identity->role) {

        case 'A':
            if ($module != 'P') {
                $this->myNotAuthorized();
            }
            break;

        // cases for other roles/modules
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are likely looking for a [Role based Access Control List](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control).
Zend Framework offers this through [`Zend_Acl`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html).

Also see:

- [Devzone: Zend_Acl / Zend_Auth example scenario](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1665)
- [Top Site about Zend_Acl](http://www.xmarks.com/topic/zend_acl)

Comment: Thanks for this.

But here I am not trying to implement ACL as I mentioned the sections also have sub sections. Section itself a panel with various modules in it and that only concerns to a particular user as P only need sec A to perform his work. section A contain sub section(modules) etc... . Same for user Q(sec-B) and R(sec-C). The section will have separate header and footer also.

Comment: @Acharya I am not sure whether I understand. Zend_Acl can be tied to Zend_Navigation, so if this is about rendering individual navigation, it's very much possible with it. You might be talking about [Multitenancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy) though. If so, please disregard my answer, but update the question accordingly.

Comment: But my question is what directory structure I should use and how should I implement multiple login. Please see above

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it a simple way by not to implement Zend_ACL if you don't want it.

Use session variables and check those on module access.